# Very Slow Internet Speeds On Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking

I have just installed Ubuntu just a few days ago and i've had problems with slow internet. On windows, it would take about 10 minutes to download one of my games. But on Ubuntu it's take about 45 minutes to download and I don't know why. There's also is no additional drivers available. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I tried this again and it didn't make a different.

### However, this may help you.

Fixed It By Going into Settings > WiFi > Gear Icon Next To Connect internet connection.

Then go to IPv6 settings.

The finally. Change the method to disabled.

And Your Done!

While Downloading Left 4 Dead 2 (A Game)

Before: 45 minute

After: 20 minutes

Also, i just found out my sister was streaming 4K video on nexflix